# Не получается спарсить текст поста в Instagram

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

**Имеется:** код парсера поста из Инстаграмма:

```
    def parse_instagram_post_(self):
        # Looking for html text of the post.
        request = requests.get(self.current_parsing_url)
        request.encoding = 'UTF-8'

        parsed_post = BeautifulSoup(request.text, features='html.parser')
        print(parsed_post)
        post_html_text = parsed_post.find('div', class_='C4VMK')

        return post_html_text
```

**Вопрос:** не получается получить текст из поста, который завернут в div класса C4VMK. Бьютифул Суп просто возвращает None значение. Помогите, пожалуйста.

**Инспекция кода:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так там специально так делается, чтобы усложнить жизнь разным аггрегаторам. К тому же, у инсты есть api: https://blog.hubspot.com/website/instagram-api-examples , https://active-vision.ru/blog/fotografii-iz-instagram-api/

Comment: не знаю есть ли разница, но я использую request.text()

Comment: The text() method of the Response interface takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with a String. The response is always decoded using UTF-8. [Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text)

Comment: @Alexandr, если использовать text метод к response, то он возвращает просто html-код страницы при том урезанный какой-то, без текста поста вообще.

Comment: @Sheridan, спасибо, попробую.

Comment: @hyper-cookie так оно не "урезано", а ты просто получил шаблон, который заполнит сверху код на жаваскрипте, подёргая инсту за данные.

Comment: чтобы нормально что то спарсить надо зайти на страницу,  которую собираешься спарсить и в контекстном меню выбрать 'Исходный код', тогда будет ясно, что приходит при первом запросе и как формируется страница